# FORMAT() is not a built in function

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I need to retrieve month and year from `GETDATE()`. I am using

```
SELECT FORMAT(GETDATE(), 'MM-yyyy')
```

and it returns the correct value as '03-2019'.
Once I apply the above code segment inside a stored procedure, it throws

> FORMAT is not a built in function

So I switched to the below statement which returns the same output.

```
SELECT RIGHT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),GETDATE(),105),7)
```

Why SQL Server returns an error message when I use `FORMAT` in a stored procedure but works with in SQL `SELECT` statement.

**Stored procedure with FORMAT() executes in SQL server 2014, but throws an error in SQL 2017**

Comment: Alexander's answer is most likely the correct one, however, you should read Aaron Bertand's [FORMAT() is nice and all, but…](https://sqlperformance.com/2015/06/t-sql-queries/format-is-nice-and-all-but). The bottom line is that format should probably be avoided when an easy convert is available - because of performance issues. Also, as a side note, you can convert to directly to `char(7)` instead of the cumbersome `varchar(10)` and then `right`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Seems like the compatibility level is set to `compatibility_level = 100`.
This corresponds to SQL Server 2008. This is why that function is not available.

Compatibility level can be checked by:

```
SELECT name, compatibility_level FROM sys.databases
```

And it can be set to the modern value by:

```
-- 140 = SQL Server 2017
ALTER DATABASE [yourDb] SET COMPATIBILITY_LEVEL = 140
```

Answer (score 0):

FORMAT function is available from version 2012 onwards.

[image]

Can you check `SELECT @@version` ?

Comment: This would also be better as a comment and not as an answer.